# Trying to create Haskell Eq instance

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to create an Eq instance for my created list type. The Eq should return true only if both list averages are equal.

```
average :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
average xs 
     | xs == [] = 0
     | otherwise = realToFrac (sum xs) / genericLength xs

data NumList a = Nlist [a]

instance Eq (NumList a) where
    (Nlist x) == (Nlist y) = (average x) == (average y)`
```

But when I try to compile this I get error:

```
No instance for (Real a) arising from a use of ‘average’
 Possible fix:
  add (Real a) to the context of the instance declaration
 In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘(average x)’
 In the expression: (average x) == (average y)
 In an equation for ‘==’:
 (Nlist x) == (Nlist y) = (average x) == (average y)
```

I am not good with haskell and trying to learn it, could some one help me with this error?

Comment: What if you have `NumList Banana`? How do you average a list of bananas?

Comment: I understand that I should make some kind of instance constraint but don't really know how to make it. How to tell it that it can only be number list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the same type constraints for your Eq instance :

```
instance (Real a) => Eq (NumList a) where
    (Nlist x) == (Nlist y) = (average x) == (average y)`
```

Comment: Damn I am stupid... I was trying `Eq (NumList a) => (Real a)` Thanks a lot